# Replacing an HTML string with shortcodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, ckeditor

### Background

I am developing a plugin for CKEditor. I need to replace some div tags with shortcodes before submitting it to the server. There is a function which gives me the content of the editor as string.

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

### What I need

There is a string containing the following markup:

```
<div class="contactblock align-left" data-contact="Peter" data-group="trainer">
<h2>Kontaktdaten</h2>
</div>

<p>...</p>

<div class="contactblock align-left" data-contact="Bernd" data-group="trainer">
<h2>Kontaktdaten</h2>
</div>

<p>...</p>
```

The result should look like that:

```html
[contactblock contact="Peter" group="trainer" align="left"]

<p>...</p>

[contactblock contact="Bernd" group="trainer" align="right"]

<p>...</p>
```

I only want to replace the div elements with the '.contactblock' class. All the other markup should stay the same.

### What I tried

After trying and searching the internet for several hours, I could not find any working solution. I ended up with the following code:

```
var $data = $(data);

$data.filter('.contactblock').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.empty();
});   

var replaced = $data.clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
```

I found this question: [jQuery `replaceWith()` for HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996237/jquery-replacewith-for-html-string). But it is not working for me. I could not even delete the inner HTML of the `div`s. I really have no more idea on what to do…

Comment: I found another similar question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211473/jquery-replace-selected-html-tags-in-string-with-value?rq=1). Maybe that will help me to find the solution. I will try out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/jtq262Lq/)

Idea is to set htmlString to a dummy div and process html elements.

```js
$("#txtInput").on("blur", function() {
  var t = $("#txtInput").val();
  $("#dummy").html(t);
  var result = "";
  var c = $("#dummy").children();
  $.each(c, function(index, el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass("contactblock")) {
      result += "[contactblock ";
      
      // Get data attributes
      var d = $(el).data()
      result += Object.keys(d).map(function(k) {
        return k + "=\"" + d[k] + "\"";
      }).join(" ");
      
      // get classes
      var _c = "";
      el.classList.forEach(function(clas){
       var reg = /^align/;
       if(clas === "contactblock"){}
        else if(reg.test(clas)){
         result += clas.split("-").join("=\"") + "\"";
        }
        else{
         _c += clas;
        }
      })
      if(_c)
       result += " class=\"" + _c + "\"";
      result += "]";
      result += "\n"
    } else {
      result += $(el)[0].outerHTML;
    }
  });
  $("#result").text(result)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtInput" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="dummy" class="hide"></div>
```